# Vertically centering a circle on a responsive D3 svg

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to draw some circles on an a responsive svg.

Here is the code for the svg:

```
const width = window.innerWidth;
const circleWidth = width / 2;
let h = 700;

const svgBackground = d3.select("#container")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${width} ${h}`)
  .classed("svg-content", true)
  .on("mouseleave", function () {
    d3.selectAll("circle.neo")
        .style("stroke", ringColour);

    d3.select("div#container")
        .selectAll("p")
        .remove();
})
```

It scales responsively but I can't figure out how to draw the circles so they are centered vertically

```
let height = svgBackground.style("height");
height = height.slice(0, (height.length - 2));
const halfHeight = height / 2;

let circles = svgBackground.selectAll("circle.neo")
        .data(radius)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "neo")

let circleAttributes = circles
        .attr("cx", circleWidth)
        .attr("cy", halfHeight)
        .attr("r", function (d) { return d })
        .style("stroke", ringColour)
        .style("fill", "none")
```

If anyone has any tips for how to do this, I would appreciate it. Here's the full code on js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ncbtdk8m/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that a part of the bottom of your SVG is not visible because `.svg-container` has a `overflow:hidden` property. This makes it appear like it was not in the center.

If you remove that CSS property and configure your height correctly things start to look different: http://jsfiddle.net/9dprfwj1/

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is the styling of the `div#container` and the `svg.svg-content`.

**No** need to use the `position` and the `display` attributes.

You don't set a `width` and `height` to the svg and you don't have a resize handler, so how can you be responsive.

Why add a new center circle each time you use the sliders.

You only get 80 stars with radius `0.5`.